# TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function (after refreshing the div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am using highcharts library for rendering the charts in a div of my website.The charts are getting rendered properly the first time but when i am refreshing that a particular div on which the chart is displayed and trying to generate the chart ,i am getting an error "**TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function**".
If I refresh the website ,the charts are once again rendered.Any help would be appreciated...:/

machine_level_default.php(The code is for the div in webpage):

```
<script src=".../jquery.js"></script>
<script src=".../jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script src="./machine_level.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>

        var array_return=null;
        var array_return1=null;
        var array_return2=null;
        var datasets;
        var categories_array=new Array();

        var placeholder=null;
        var plot2=null;
            var d1=null;

        var stack = 0,
            bars = true,
            lines = false,
            steps = false;
    $('#machine_level_select').hide();
    $('#placeholder').html('<h1><b>Select From Options on the left</b></h1>');

    $('#startDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy', minDate: -30, maxDate: -0 });

    $(document).ready(function(){



        $.ajax({type:'POST',url:generic_selector,data:'gen_sel_tab=22&user_group='+user_group}).done(function(data){
                $('#machine_level_select_time_start').html(data);                   
            });
        $.ajax({type:'POST',url:generic_selector,data:'gen_sel_tab=23&user_group='+user_group}).done(function(data){
                $('#machine_level_select_time_end').html(data);                 
            });


    });

</script>


    <table id='dash_info' width='100%' height='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td class='info-td' width='20%'>
                    <div id='dash_pane_heading'>Meters</div>
                    <div >
                        <table>

                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Start Time</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div id='machine_level_select_time_start'>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>End Time</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div id='machine_level_select_time_end'>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class='input-glow' style='margin-left:auto;margin-right:1%;' id='startDate' placeholder='Start Date' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td align='center'>
                                    <input id='chart_bars' class='button_main_1' type='submit' tabindex='10' value='Go' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr id='machine_level_select' style='display:none;'>
                                <td>Graph Type</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div >
                                        <select id='machine_level_select_option' width='30%'>
                                            <option>select here</option>
                                            <option id='machine_level_select_line' selected='selected'>Line </option>
                                            <option id='machine_level_select_bars' >Bar </option>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class='info-td' >
                    <div id='ododiv1'>

                        <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" style='width:100%;height:100%;'></div>

                    </div>
                </td>



            </tr>
        </table>
```

machine_level.js:

```
$('#chart_bars').click(function()
    {
        start_date=$("#startDate").val();

        start_time=$("#machine_level_select_start_time").val();
        //alert(start_time);
        end_time=$("#machine_level_select_end_time").val();

        var x=end_time-start_time;

        for(var i=(start_time/100);i<=(end_time/100);i++)
        {
            categories_array.push(i+'00hrs');
        }
                    //alert(x);
        if(x<=0)
        {   
            alert("End time cannot be less than start time.");
            return ;
        }
        if(start_date==null|| start_date=='' )
        {
            alert("Enter start and/or end date");
            return ;
        }
        $('#machine_level_select').hide();
        $('#placeholder').html('<img src=./common/images/main/loading.gif />');
        $.ajax({type:'POST',url:'modules/machine_level/require_highcharts.php',async :false,dataType:'json', data:'user_group='+user_group+'&start_date='+start_date+'&start_time='+start_time+'&end_time='+end_time}).done(function(result){
            //alert(result);
            datasets=result;
            $("#machine_level_select_line").trigger( "click" );
            $('#machine_level_select').show();

        });

    });

    $(document).on('click','#machine_level_select_bars',function()
    {
        //alert(categories_array);

        $('#placeholder').html('');
        $('#placeholder').highcharts({
             chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'KWH Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories_array,
                title: {
                    text: 'Time'
                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'KWH Consumption'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} KWH</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            series:datasets



        });
    });


    $(document).on('click','#machine_level_select_line',function()
    {

        $('#placeholder').html('');
        $('#placeholder').highcharts
        ({
             title: {
                text: 'KWH Consumption',
                x: -20 //center
            },

            xAxis: {
                 categories: categories_array,
                 title: {
                    text: 'Time'
                },

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Meters'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },   
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' KWH'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: datasets,

        }); 
    });
```

PS: the ajax data which is returned from the require_highcharts.php is correct.

Comment: Please paste your code...

Comment: Why do you have this line: `$('#placeholder').html('');`? Highcharts will automatically remove previously created chart in that div to make space for new one.

Comment: @PawełFus...Even if i Remove that line of code,it still shows the same error

Comment: Okay, then some simple question - why don't you have **ALL** of code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`? You can have several times that line, just to make sure all code is executed after all libraries are loaded. Also, don't you have any other errors in console?

Comment: I did what you asked me to put the code in $(document).ready(function(){ ... });...it still gave me the same error ...and there is no other error in console @PawełFus

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Instead of AJAX just use some static data.